# Book on Data Structure in PHP

Tags: php, data-structures

I am looking for book on data structure which guides in linked list, double linked list etc and bubble sort etc. I need implementation as well as theory part.

Comment: I would recommend you consider data structure books in a language other than php. Much of what you will learn makes little sense implementing in php, although the knowledge will still be useful.

Comment: Just for info and it may give you joy when you know that Yahoo! India is taking interview based on that. They even ask DS to GUI + PHP guy.

Comment: Here are few sorting implementation in PHP: http://www.phptutorialonline.com/php-algorithms.aspx. I have decided to get my job done (quickfix) using similar link with Wiki help. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort). I feel a book in needed on this matter using PHP. PHP guys are simpler. So, it will be easy to read those books.

Comment: Why the minus point to my Question?

Comment: Get a good book on algorithms and data structures, and forget about the PHP requirement.  It's the concepts that you need to master.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a book but a blog post by Matthew Turland walks you through the [SPL Datastructures](http://de.php.net/manual/en/spl.datastructures.php) (including Lists) and was recently (12/14/2010) updated for PHP 5.3.4 and Ubuntu 10.10:

- http://matthewturland.com/2010/05/20/new-spl-features-in-php-5-3/

If you want to know how these are implemented in PHP, head to the SVN

- http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/ext/spl/

Comment: This is just a discussion. I am looking for little theory and PHP implementation. I got the theory part on wikipedia. and for implementation I am  checking individual blogs for different different structures.

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend [The Algorithm Design Manual by Steven Skiena](http://www.algorist.com/) ([Google books link](http://books.google.ru/books?id=7XUSn0IKQEgC&lpg=PR1&ots=z6eGNRJR1l&dq=algorithm%20design%20manual&pg=PR1#v=onepage&q&f=false)) - it's one of the best books about algorithms and data structures I ever read. BTW, examples are given in C language.

Comment: This book can be good if I want to master algo and DS part in very details. Thanks for sharing. I will think of it. But right now I am in mood of quick fix.

Answer (score 1):

The name escapes me, but someone had an open source data structure library in java, and I think it was for a book. They ported it to php. I think the name started with an O.

google isn't helping me. Too many link and blog spam sites occupy these topics.

edit--- found it
http://www.brpreiss.com/books/opus11/

Comment: right! I was also reached there and found lots of PHP codes. Some of the algorithms I am concerned with are also there. I am using Wiki for description and those code or other at net for reference. Thanks for the info though. Given a point to you as well. :)